# Is there any way to limit the concurrent request thread of Selenium Chromedriver?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium

Hi folks I'm begginer to selenium.

I am using strom proxies for some **scraping** tasks. The limit of my package is 40 threads simultaneously. But for best result I have to use 25% of my package at a time. As each chrome driver tab consume 10 thread.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Most likey no. To be fair, it isn't ChromeDriver using the threads. It is Google Chrome. This might be a good read: [Why does Chrome have so many open processes?](https://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/).

Comment: So what is the solution to this problem? Is there any work around?

Comment: Download the source code for the Chromium Project, and reengineer How it manages processes? Other than that, there is no solution.